# Meteor: store object in rendered() to be used in child helpers

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to store an object that I create during `Template.myTemplate.rendered = function ( ) { ... }` and use that object in `Template.myChildTemplate.helpers(helpers)`. So far I'm resorting to using a global object, but that feels very hacky. Is there a nice Template-centric way of doing this?

Comment: For anyone interested, I wrote a blog post on [scoped reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) which details the technique described in Akshat's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UI._templateInstance();` and `ReactiveDict` (to make your data reactive too) (added with `meteor add reactive-dict`

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function() {
    this.templatedata = new ReactiveDict();

}
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
    this.templatedata.set("myname", "value";
};

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    myvalue: function() {
        var tmpl = UI._templateInstance();
        return tmpl.templatedata.get('myname');
    }
});
```

This will allow you to use this template multiple times on the page, and still have a variable scope to each template, which global variables or non instance variables wouldn't allow.

A note of warning, the current iron router (0.7.1) breaks `UI._templateInstance();`, which is an [open bug](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/691) at the moment.

Comment: Is `templatedata` persistent during rerendering?

Comment: If the template is destroyed the variable is destroyed too. I'm not sure blaze re-renders templates anymore. If the templates stuff (dom/or helper values) changes it will persist, though

Comment: Right. I wonder how this relates to [`this.data`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_data), the docs still mark it as read-only and updated on re-render. In the past I used it to store local data with success if I avoided rerendering the template.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. `this.data` changes when the parent template's data context changes, so you can change it and will persist, so long as the parent template doesn't change its data. This basically stores the data in the template's instance so as long as its alive you can access it and set stuff on it (including if there are multiple templates), if the data context changes the data will still persist too.

Comment: I cant wait to use it, My app is littered with per template `Deps.autorun` and stuff, this would clean it up alot for me. Just waiting for iron-router to support it

Comment: Same here - I have a new feature which uses exactly this technique. I've been sitting on it since RC1 because of the IR incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such method **yet**, unfortunately.

The common pattern is to use reactive dict either as a file-wide variable, or in a namespace related to the template if you need the access in several files. The downside of this solution is that such variable is shared among all instances of the same template, so you have to work around this if you render this template in more than one place.

```
var data = new ReactiveDict();

Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
  data.set('key', 'value');
};
```